# Unable to get tap event on status bar iOS 13

Tags: ios13, swift5

Till iOS12, I was using following code to handle tap event on status bar:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    let statusBarRect = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        guard let touchPoint = event?.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.window) else { return }
        if statusBarRect.contains(touchPoint) {
            //Status bar tapped
        }
    }            
}
```

But, now it's not working for iOS 13. Please help me on the same.

Comment: In `iOS13` `statusBarFrame` is deprecated.

Comment: @Sunil Maurya Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

A view in your app that's behind the status bar cannot be touched. You should not be trying, in your app, to detect a tap "on the status bar"; it isn't even part of your app (it's a window imposed by the runtime). It can't be done.